# How does the extension get the secret information about the build task in Team Foundation Server extension

Tags: node.js, git, tfs, azure-devops

Reading the vsts document, using nodejs to develop a build task extension, 
but can not get the task related to the confidential configuration information.

1. I configured a remote git build task in tfs server, global variables only get git url and branch,no git username and password.How to get other infomation.below code

```

```
import tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');

console.log(tl.getVariables());
```

2. There is no password type due to the build task configuration option,in the variable configuration which adds a variable and encryption,then get $(password) is null.How do I define a ciphertext configuration in plain text to my plugin processing code.
3. Task with a dynamic property getting data from an endpoint REST data source,How to send post requests, and how handle the different data format returned by endpoint server.[endpoint demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/extend/develop/service-endpoints)

sorry,many question

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret variables are not decrypted into environment variables. So, scripts and programs run by your build steps are not given access by default.

You can add the input textbox(es) in the task of build/release and pass secret variable(s) (e.g. Password) through them.

Regarding get endpoint information through nodejs, there are many functions, such as `getEndpointUrl`, `GetEndPointDataParameter` etc…, check [VSTS-TASK-LIB TYPESCRIPT API](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/vsts-task-lib.md).

There is a blog contains using endpoings in task implementation section: [Service endpoints – Overview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sriramb/2016/09/14/service-endpoints-overview/)

Comment: Great blog.I do other work ,forget to thank you!emm.. For  `dataSourceBindings.parameters` in task.json, I still have any doubts.I saw the tfs server's http request body inside the parameters I configured, but my external endpoint server cannot get any params.>.<

Comment: @soulxy Can you provide the sample data to explain it?

Comment: I may not explain myself well, so created a temporary [git repository](https://github.com/soulxy/tfsdemo).When visiting $(endpoint.url)/userlist, my external endpoint server cannot get params.

Comment: [/task/task.json](https://github.com/soulxy/tfsdemo/blob/master/task/task.json)  is the file which I used in my project.

Comment: @soulxy You need to add a input box to let user to select a connection (service endpoint), there is the sample [Service Endpoints in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/service-endpoints)

Comment: sorryyy,I really missing endpoint service input in this demo.But I wrote it in real project. My endpoint serice is working well just to get no http params.

Comment: @soulxy Do you mean url parameter? Provide the detail code here.

Comment: "dataSourceBindings": [{
        "target": "userlist",
        "endpointId": "$(XYService)",
        "dataSourceName": "XY Userlist",
        "parameters": {
            "data": "$(msg)"
        },
        "resultTemplate": "{\"Value\":\"{{{ value }}}\",\"DisplayValue\":\"{{{ value }}}\"}"
    }]                

the problem is that the parameter "data" is not passed into the endpoint service "XYService"

Comment: @soulxy Do you have data parameter in the URL? Sample: endpoint type defines `"endpointUrl": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$(endpoint.subscriptionId)/resourceGroups/$(ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$(WebAppName)/slots?api-version=2015-08-01"`,  Task.json:  `"parameters": {
                "WebAppName": "$(WebAppName)",
                "ResourceGroupName": "$(ResourceGroupName)"`
            },

Comment: WebAppName and ResourceGroupName parameters.

Comment: TT I got it!! I always think the params  is part of http body, and attempt to make post http.